# How to put labels into frames with tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm trying to create two frames and to put 2 labels into te second one. This is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

f1 = tk.Frame(root, bg = "red", width = 400, height = 250)
f2 = tk.Frame(root, bg = "blue", width = 400, height = 150)

f1.pack()
f2.pack()

text1 = tk.Label(f2, text = "lala")
text1.pack(side='left')

text2 = tk.Label(f2, text = "lalala")
text2.pack(side= "right")

root.mainloop()
```

Why do neither the backgroundcolour of f2 nor the side settings work?

When I run the code, it looks like this:

[image]

I want it to look like this:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: f2 doesn't have any content and therefore wont appear i think

Comment: `width`/`height` of a Frame normally only apply when it has no children.  A Frame containing widgets will shrink to fit them, which may result in little or none of its background color actually being visible.

Comment: When I run the code, nothing works. As you can see now in the picture

Comment: Could you sketch what you want it to look like?

Comment: Yes, I just added it to the question

Comment: add `f2.pack_propagate(0)` after the `f2.pack()` line.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example with `f2.pack_propagate(0)` added, plus the addition of anchor keywords to more closely match the example output above (thanks [acw1668](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5317403/acw1668))

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")

f1 = tk.Frame(root, bg = "red", width = 400, height = 250)
f2 = tk.Frame(root, bg = "blue", width = 400, height = 150)

f1.pack()
f2.pack()
f2.pack_propagate(0)

text1 = tk.Label(f2, bg='blue', text = "lala")
text1.pack(side='left', anchor='n')

text2 = tk.Label(f2, bg='blue', text = "lalala")
text2.pack(side= "right", anchor='n')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Need to add `anchor="n"` to `grid(...)` in order to put the two labels at the corners.

Comment: `pack_propagate` will almost certainly lead to other problems once the OP starts adding more widgets.

Comment: @BryanOakley Sorry it should be `pack(...)` instead of `grid(...)`.